# Use Platform Cache to cache ~50 records from a custom object

Tags: cache, platform-cache

We have a custom object that realistically should have been Custom Metadata / Custom Settings as it stores background metadata that controls how pages within our Community load.

It has been very expensive to fetch any time we'd like to update the page, so I'm wondering if Platform Cache would be a solution for this?  My reticence is that it seems primed to handle only a few values (not 15 fields on 50 records = 750 values).

Has anyone worked on this use case?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a good use case for Platform Cache, specifically the org-level cache. The challenge is sizing the cache partition(s) versus your data. From the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_platform_cache_limits.htm):

> **Org Cache Limits**
>
> Maximum size of a single cached item (for put() methods: 100 KB
>
> Maximum local cache size for a partition, per-request:    1,000 KB

Best-case scenario: your entire dataset of 50 records weighs less than or equal to 1 MB and each record is less than or equal to 100 KB. You can stuff the entire dataset into a single partition and live happily ever after.

Average and worst-case scenarios are left as an exercise to the reader.